# How to detect tag content in tags and replace(move) them in other tags content place?

Tags: php, regex

I'm a beginner to php, specially with regex stuff, so what I'm trying to do is to get content from tags who are in other tags like this

`<td>
    <br>(content)<br>
</td>`

what I've done so far is to get data into array chunks

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$url = '(url_here)';

$htmlstr = str_get_html(file_get_contents($url));
$matches1 = [];
preg_match_all("'<td>(.*?)(</td>|</<td>)'si", $htmlstr, $matches1);
$data1 = array_chunk($matches1[0], 6, FALSE);
```

but the problem is in some rows with td tags I'm getting br tag content too like this

How to detect those inner tags, how to get that content and move it into other other tags content space?

Here's an example what I'm facing in some rows [link_here](https://gyazo.com/e5c52eb13d6d6d3a4e871be6e057ec21)

Comment: You should add a better example because `<br>` is a self-closing tag without children text nodes and doesn't enclose `(content)`.

Comment: Don't put a link to a png in comments, edit your question to write a good and well explained example. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use regex for HTML, [since there is no and will never be a 100% working solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/6622577).

Use HTML Parsers instead, like the built-in one ([DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)) or a user contributed one (like [PHP-HTML-Parser](https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser))

When using DOMDocument, you can select the tags you want kinda like javascript can:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($yourHTML);

$tds = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');
```

Comment: @Maluel, you're right thanks. For those who has familiar issues found a useful link [link_here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1074174/Simple-Way-to-Convert-HTML-Table-Data-into-PHP-Arr)